# Failed Audit on a page that looks good

Tags: discussion, support, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit, low-quality-answers

I just failed an audit on this review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32669544

Stack Overflow tells me

> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. This post has severe quality issues. It is abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable – readers will find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful. Please delete or recommend deletion when reviewing such posts.

I don't understand what is wrong with the post, am I missing something entirely obvious?

It also tells me

> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately

Well I am worrying and I'm not convinced its been handled appropriately.

Here is the body of the post:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps its a cut and paste of another answer?

Comment: Can't find anything even close to matching it so that's unlikely

Comment: The code and half the answer are copied *from its link*. The attribution could probably be a bit clearer. I notice that the answer was flagged as "spam or offensive content" and deleted. FWIW, the linked page is, for something purporting to be documentation, quite poorly written. I'm assuming `nuget.org` is a hosting site for just *whatever* random packages, analogous to PyPI.

Comment: Another day, another unfair review audit.

Answer (score 58):

(not the moderator who handled these, but...)

The issue here is *undisclosed affiliation*.  The user posted 5 answers, all linking libraries from one company), and an investigation confirmed that there was in fact an affiliation between the user and the linked content (for privacy reasons, I can't say how that was determined) which was not disclosed per [our policy on promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Of course, you couldn't have known that, since you can't see a user's deleted posts.

The way to avoid this is for the moderator who flags the post to pick "Rude or abusive" instead of "Spam" when deleting stuff like this, but that's difficult to remember in the moment since it's rather unintuitive (it *is* spam, after all).  This one slipped through the cracks.  I'm undeleting and reflagging the posts from this user in order to remove them from the audit pool, and I also gave a PSA in our mod room about using R/A flags instead of Spam.

Comment: Great, thanks for the detailed and understandable answer. I assume if the moderator had flagged this post as "Rude or abusive" instead of "Spam" the outcome for me would have been indistinguishable. Highlighting this from the point of view from a new reviewer who sees a message like this, its confusing and demoralising when you are told you have gotten it wrong because the content is "Rude or abusive" when there is absolutely no indication of rudeness or that the post was somehow abusive. The experience makes me less likely to continue reviewing.

Comment: @htaccess the difference between Spam and R/A flags is that posts with a helpful R/A flag are not used as review audits, so we can use them for posts that are spam but not obviously so without additional context.  Apologies for the bad experience here; your review of that post was totally fine.

Comment: Ok, yes then that does sound like a solution in this case, thanks for the clarification. Thanks for the apology as well because while unnecessary given the explanation it does make me feel better! Based on this response I think I'll give reviewing another chance ;)

Comment: Would it be easier for mods if you were able to indicate whether or not a spam post should be in the audit pool when flagging it? I would support a feature request that made your jobs easier.

Comment: Yes, @BSMP. That would be much easier for both us mods and for reviewers. Unlike most of the features we want, that one is already implemented. It's called a "rude or abusive" flag.

Comment: If there were infinite dev time for my random whims, I'd maybe change the text for moderators to "Obvious spam" and "Rude, abusive, or non-obvious spam" but...I doubt that would be worth the dev time it would take to do.  Ultimately, it's a weird quirk of the system that only 25 people need to remember, and hardly the wrongest thing about that part of the system (did you know that the mod tools UI strongly implies that we should simply _delete_ spam and R/A content instead of flagging it ourselves, despite the fact that that would avoid the correct penalties being applied?).

Comment: It's like we need a "don't use this for audit" flag somewhere. There's been quite a few really bad audit questions that simply shouldn't be used despite being handled correctly.

Comment: There is one. If it's been touched by a mod, by HNQ, or posted to twitter/blog/anywhere by SO, it shouldn't be an audit.

Comment: like, by definition, mods are exception handlers, they handle exceptions, audits shouldn't be testing regular users on exceptions.

Comment: @CodyGray Well, no, that's not what 'rude or abusive' means.

Comment: @KevinB This one was deleted by Community, not a mod.

Comment: It is *precisely* what it means, @TylerH, both because these are posts that are considered to be an *abuse* of the system and/or its resources, and because the definition of the "rude or abusive" flag in the context of Stack Overflow has an expanded definition for moderators based on its behavior as defined by the system implementation and our internal documentation. Note that this is *not* a request for regular users to flag non-obvious spam as "rude or abusive" or otherwise consider what effect their flags will have on audits. I agree that would be inappropriate.

Comment: @KevinB Well...part of the issue is that we also do a lot of things that normal users do, just...faster (and hopefully more accurately, based on some of the stuff I see the LQA queue delete sometimes...).  We flag a lot of the obvious spam posts, for instance, just usually not as the first flag.  Avoiding using posts red-flagged _only_ by a moderator would go some way, and isn't a bad idea, but then [this one](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/386547) would still have qualified, since it was flagged by a regular user when the context was still visible.

Comment: @TylerH "flagged as spam or offensive content and deleted by Community" means that it was deleted by red flags (or account removal, in less common cases), and the fact that it doesn't have at least 6 downvotes means that the last red flag was cast by a moderator.  It only shows the moderator's name if we delete without flagging.

Comment: *The way to avoid this is for the moderator who flags the post to pick "Rude or abusive" instead of "Spam" when deleting stuff like this* — good to know that moderators are incentivised to engage in insincere voting just as much as regular users…

Comment: @RyanM That is still _technically_ deleted by community, not a moderator. My point is a system that checks "was this deleted by a moderator" wouldn't mark this one as "yes".

Comment: @CodyGray No, "don't include this as an audit in the review queue" is **not** at all included, implied, or inferrable from "flag this post is rude or abusive", whether the person doing the flagging is a moderator or not.

Answer (score 16):

Again, it feels like posts deleted by mods rather than the regular reviews/user delete votes should *not* be picked for audits, since moderators have a lot of big picture and behind-the-scenes info that regular users lack.

- This needlessly pisses off reviewers doing correct reviews or incorrectly hands out automatic review suspensions preventing them from reviewing.
- It it a waste of diamond mod time to endlessly research why exactly yet another broken audit was broken this time. And then manually remove bans if needed etc.

The review queues is at some all time high currently. Crap Overflow, but SO the company does not care - no amount of repeated criticism against broken audits over the past 5-10 years has caused the company to take action. The audits will not be fixed until we all boycott unpaid review work. If they don't wish to fix the audits, the company can hire staff to do the reviews.

Comment: Neither you nor I want them hiring staff to do the reviews. This would have about the same result as clearing the review queues and marking all posts as "good", save for possibly taking longer.